# Hide Payment Method WooCommerce after Failure of first try

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide the payment method once user click place order using payment method lets say 'B' which returns in failure of payment.

```
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if($this->api->somemethod()){
        // Payment complete
        $order->payment_complete(); 
        return array(
            'result' => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $order )
        );
    }
    else {
        wc_add_notice( pll__('Payment error: You cannot use this payment method, Choose another method '), 'error' );
        return; 
    }
}
```

I have used following filter

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways',  'add_gateway_cb'  );
```

But it only works on page reload. I want something which works with Ajax process payment or at least triggers the payment methods to reload upon failure.

Alternatively:
I can use custom JS on place order click.